# Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof firebase'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I see `typeOf` error on `default` keyword. Here are my imports:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; 
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

export class PostsService {

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }
countViews(postId: any){
    const viewCount= {
      views: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) //only issue is with default
    }
    this.afs.doc(`posts/${postId}`).update(viewCount).then(() => {
      console.log("VIEWS updated"); //this works
      
    })
  }
}
```

Dependencies in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6",
    "firebase-tools": "^12.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

The following should capture the current value on no. of views on a post.

```
views: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```

I updated my import statemnts as shown earlier. I did see a similar question posted on stackoverflow, but the answers don't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

`firebase` does not have `default` property. Just use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment`. And also you should imprt `firebase/compat`.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat';

:

  views: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```